# What is the android equivalent of this iOS ReactNative implementation?

Tags: java, android, react-native

Does anyone have examples using @ReactMethod within a SimpleViewManager on android?

I need the android equivalent of this https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/ios/RCTMapboxGL/RCTMapboxGLManager.m#L60